# Angular Run some code after service finish to Upload files

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage

I have this service function I use to Upload Files to Firebase Storage.
It receives an array of files and upload each file of it.
It also updates the loading status of each file, and fills the 'url' of the file when it is uploaded.

So, my **component.ts** looks like

```
files: [{name: 'file1', uploaded: false, url:''}, {name: 'file2', uploaded: false, url:''} ];

...

constructor( private myService: FirebaseService) { }

...

this.myService.uploadImgToFirebase(this.files);
```

The thing is, I need to run some code in my component ( something like *this.SOME_ITEM.files = this.files* ) but just when *ALL* the files were uploaded.

```
this.myService.uploadImgToFirebase(this.files);

// THINGS I NEED TO DO WHEN ALL THE FILES WERE UPLOADED
```

How can I achieve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Assuming` you are making an `http` call which would return an `observable` which you can subscribe.

```
this.myService.uploadImgToFirebase(this.files).subscribe(m => {
   //Do your operations here once its done.
});
```

You can look at `async/await`

```
async function turnYourFunctionAsync() {
  return 100;
}

turnYourFunctionAsync().then(alert); // 100
```

Another simple with async/await:

```
async function turnYourFunctionAsync() {
    let promise = new Promise((res, err) => {
        setTimeout(() => res("The file upload operation is complete"), 1000)
    });

    let response = await promise; 

    alert(response); 
    }
};

turnYourFunctionAsync();
```

Comment: Hi @Thalaivar, thanks for your answer. But no.  I'm not making and http call. But your aproach can help. How can I transform a simple function, into a function that returns an Observable ?

Comment: You could use asyc/await to turn your normal JS function which would return a promise. running the above code in chrome console would pring you 100.